# Cronjob not working no matter what

Tags: server, cron, raspberrypi

I have installed Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS for Raspberry Pi 64bit on a Raspberry Pi 4. I have set a cronjob with `sudo crontab e` from my regular user (which actually will set contents to root's crontab), the rule is,

```
@reboot sleep 20 && /home/ubuntu/mount_usb.sh
```

This is supposed to run at boot, right? But it doesn't. I have also tried run it with time interval (with [run-one](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/run-one) because I need that script to run once), like this,

```
1 * * * * run-one /home/ubuntu/mount_usb.sh
```

Which didn't work either. Content of this script is,

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/tmux new-session -d -s usb_watcher '/usr/bin/python3.8 /home/ubuntu/watch_driver.py'
```

I have also tried like this,

```
#!/bin/sh
source /home/ubuntu/.profile
tmux new-session -d -s usb_watcher '/usr/bin/python3.8 /home/ubuntu/watch_driver.py
```

Also like this,

```
#!/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/bin/
tmux new-session -d -s usb_watcher '/usr/bin/python3.8 /home/ubuntu/watch_driver.py
```

If you are wondering what's inside this `watch_driver.py`, then please [check it here](https://github.com/IamLizu/aos-summer19-20/blob/master/main.py).

cron log looks like this (`grep CRON /var/log/syslog`),

```
Sep 10 06:36:43 ubuntu CRON[1869]: (root) CMD (sleep 20 && /home/ubuntu/mount_usb.sh)
```

This is what I see when I execute `sudo systemctl status cron`,

```
● cron.service - Regular background program processing daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/cron.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Thu 2020-09-10 06:36:42 UTC; 4min 43s ago
       Docs: man:cron(8)
   Main PID: 1813 (cron)
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 4434)
     CGroup: /system.slice/cron.service
             └─1813 /usr/sbin/cron -f

Sep 10 06:36:42 ubuntu systemd[1]: Started Regular background program processing daemon.
Sep 10 06:36:42 ubuntu cron[1813]: (CRON) INFO (pidfile fd = 3)
Sep 10 06:36:42 ubuntu cron[1813]: (CRON) INFO (Running @reboot jobs)
Sep 10 06:36:43 ubuntu CRON[1837]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Sep 10 06:36:43 ubuntu CRON[1869]: (root) CMD (sleep 20 && /home/ubuntu/mount_usb.sh)
Sep 10 06:37:03 ubuntu CRON[1837]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
```

If the cron job ran, it was supposed to create a `tmux` session, like this,

```
usb_watcher: 1 windows (created Thu Sep 10 07:21:00 2020)
```

But it doesn't. I am sure there's something I am missing. Looked at some threads, maybe its something to do with the user running cron, but can't seem to figure out, tried changing the user (to run from my regular user), didn't work either, maybe I did it wrong. Please advise.

Comment: How did you install `pyudev`? Was it via `pip` or `apt`?  Do you have `sudo` set to not prompt for a password? You also have things redirect to `mount_loc_output.txt` but you don't specify a full path (you don't know what relative cron is running from).

Comment: If you did `sudo crontab -e`, you're editing root's crontab. If you want to run it as your "regular user", just do `crontab -e`.

Comment: @muru, well, the intention was to include this on roots tab.

Comment: Then make that clear. You have said "from my regular user", "tried changing the user", so it's not clear who you want this to run as.

Comment: @BrianTurek, `pyudev` via pip, well, when I usually executed command with `sudo` in a manually created `tmux` session, it didn't ask for password. So, I thought it will work. Should I set the `sudo`(s) with password in one line? Okay, I will specify the absolute path of `mount_*.txt`.

Comment: I don't know if this is the case here but, in general, cron runs with a VERY limited environment.  It's possible that the PYTHONPATH in cron isn't including `pip` installed packages as they're installed into `/usr/local`.  What are the permissions on `/home/ubuntu/mount_usb.sh`?

Comment: @BrianTurek, I see, but is pyudev even available via apt, i need to check. The script has 755 permission.

Comment: @BrianTurek, just a second thought, that cronjob was supposed to executed with the root user right? So, although I have written sudo, that is actually void, isn't?

Comment: If you're running it as root, the calls to `sudo` shouldn't be a problem but they're also completely unnecessary.

Comment: @BrianTurek, yes, indeed. But I need to run tests as regular users so I added `sudo`.